# Fake dynamic array using array structure in Java

Tags: java, arrays, resize, nullpointerexception

Here's what I'm trying to do and the problem I'm having: I want to "fake" the way to a dynamic array. That means, using a normal array structure, and whenever it's full, I would create a new array of about 25% more size than the old one and then copy the elements of the old array into the new one.

```
// Whenever my original nodes array is full
Node aNew[];
aNew = new Node[newDesiredSize];
//I create every new element in the new array for this to be a deep copy
for (int i=0; i<numVert; i++){
     aNew[i] = new Node(nodes[i].getId());
}
nodes = aNew;
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, for when I try to fill and access my newly created array, I get a `NullPointerException` error.

I've been fighting with this notion of faking the way to a dynamic array but I'm obviously missing something.

Using `ArrayList` or any other form of truly dynamic structures is not allowed.

/*********/

EDIT: Upon suggestion, I changed

```
aNew[i] = new Node(nodes[i].getId());
```

to

```
aNew[i] = nodes[i];
```

But this doesn't seem to be solving the problem.

I also checked for null places for all i's and it turns out that I have. The program seems to be "loosing" the whole newly grown part.

/***/

Solved! It was a problem with the addition of new elements upon the growth. It's all good now. Thanks for your help. Will post more info for future references.

Comment: check if nodes[i] is null for some i

Comment: ArrayList is implemented with the same idea actually (the expansion factor is different, though).

Comment: @gefei: Yes, I'm having null i's in ranges where I souldn't have. I thought this was something that had to do with deep or shallow copying, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @JakubZaverka Any method that tries to access any of the new positions upon the growth throws the NPE.

Comment: Well the new positions are empty after the enlargement, aren't they? You just copy the elements to a bigger array, and the rest is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the NPE is caused by the getId call.

But why create a new node anyway? Just:

```
aNew[i] = nodes[i];
```

Your new array should contain the same objects as old array, not clones of them.

Plus once it's all working, as an optimisation, look at `System.arrayCopy` to remove the need for the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use the source :-) `java.util.ArrayList` does that. See for example the `grow()` method

Comment: It uses the Arrays.copyOf that's part of java.utils.*, and I'm not supposed to use anything from that library.

Comment: and did you look at the source for `Arrays.copyOf()` ?